# How do you use `HtmlFirDump` in a Kotlin K2 compiler plugin?

Tags: kotlin

So, in K1, there was `IrElement.dump()`, which lets you look at the structure of a class.

K2 has `HtmlFirDump`, which I think may do sort of the same thing.

I`m thinking that a reasonable way to create a compiler plugin is to dump the structure of the input class, write code that represents what you want the plugin output to look like, and then figure out how to convert from the input to the output.

Unfortunately, I can't find any examples of how to use `HtmlFirDump`, I'm guessing because if people are using it, they use it during development and then get rid of it when everything is working.

Can anybody provide an example of how to dump the FIR structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's an internal thing not intended for external use. However, you can try. You can look into `class FirResolveModularizedTotalKotlinTest` in Kotlin repo as an example how to use it (e.g. `fun dumpFirHtml`).

An alternative (more simple) FIR renderer is `fun FirElement.render(): String` from `compiler/fir/tree/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/fir/Utils.kt`.

Comment: Thank you! I also realized after this that I can use `-Xphases-to-dump`, which makes things much easier.